# Liquibase: difference between 'initiallyDeferred' and 'deferrable'

Tags: database, liquibase

I understand why the deferred parameter is needed, but the presence of two parameters 'initiallyDeferred' and 'deferrable' in the liquidbase script is a little confusing, I can’t find anything specific in the documentation except something like 'initiallyDeferred - Defines whether constraints are initially deferred' (very useful, thanks!).
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify which database you use; I guess *all* of them - that support such options - behave the same.

This is Oracle.

By default (if you don't specify anything), constraint is created as `non deferrable` which means that possible violation is reported *at once*.

On the other hand, you can choose to set it to be `deferrable` and - if you do - then you have two more options to specify:

- whether it is `initially immediate` (validation is done immediately, whenever you insert, modify or delete rows from that table) or
- `initially deferrable` (which means that validation will "wait" until `commit`).

---

If you wonder when to use `deferred initially deferrable` constraint, then: I usually use it when two tables reference each other, i.e. have foreign key constraints that point from one table to another and vice versa.

It means that - if there was no such a possibility (deferring the constraint) - you wouldn't be able to insert rows into any of these tables because

- if you insert row into the 1st table, foreign key constraint would fail because parent key (in the 2nd table) doesn't exist yet
- if you try to insert a row into the 2nd table first (hoping to circumvent the error), you wouldn't succeed because it is now parent key in the 1st table that is missing

It means that you'd have to drop or disable (at least one) foreign key constraint(s), insert rows, and enable (or crate) them back.